# How to pre-cache components in custom service worker in angular

Tags: angular, caching, service-worker

I want to write my own service worker in my angular project. I don't want to use @angular/pwa or any other library,  I want to write from scratch for learning purpose.

I registered service worker successfully. Now I want to pre-cache components like app-component etc..

In normal projects, we can do it very easily, but in angular, we have ts file so how to pre-cache angular components, please help me!

```
const cacheNames = ['static-v1'];
const [ STATIC_CACHE ] = cacheNames;

const staticAssets = [
   // App component here
];

self.addEventListener('install', async event => { 
    const cache = await caches.open(STATIC_CACHE);
    cache.addAll(staticAssets);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no concept of caching component itself. What you should cache are `js, css, fonts, png, jpg and e.t.c`.

When you have a Single Page Application, It's somehow presumable that you use some kind of tool (such as `Webpack`).

You create a `service-worker.js` file in your src file and you add this in there:

```js
const staticAssets = [
   '/main.bundle.js`
];
```

Then you use `webpack` to copy this file into the root directory of `dist` folder.

If you have hashes in your webpack-generated files, `Cache.addAll` won't help you. In this case and many other cases, I'd strongly recommend using [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workboxQgQJYvwZg8QZoAHAAeACAAe0CiAGjC5IBBzAuMS4xLjOYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjIuMnusdToAhXlD2MBHeMhBe4Q4dUDCAc&uact=5)